# SQL delete records only which are not in conflict with Foreign Constraint

Tags: t-sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

How can I delete the records from a table that are not referenced by any record in other tables via FK?

I'm using SQL Server 2014. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonName varchar(20) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, 'Alistair'), (2, 'Bob'), (3, 'Cecile')

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID));
INSERT INTO Orders values (1), (1), (3)

DELETE FROM Persons //-->The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint FK__Orders__PersonID...
```

I only want to delete *Bob* from Persons (as there's no order belongs to him) and keep *Alistair* and *Cecile* (and no error message of course).

Motivation: I need this for a maintenance job which removes obsolete or unneeded records. The solution I can think of `DELETE FROM Persons WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE Orders.PersonID = Persons.PersonID)`
is not really good, as in my real database there are many tables and FKs and also if someone introduces another FK, my code breaks. So looking for a more generic solution.

UPDATE: just to expand why I'm looking for another solution than `DELETE ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` is that there are multiple tables in my database and I would need to list manually all of them in WHERE clause like `DELETE ... WHERE NOT EXISTS(...Table1...) AND NOT EXISTS(...Table2...) ... AND NOT EXISTS(...TableN...)` and if a developer adds `TableN+1`, my code also needs changing.
So I'm hoping to have some SQL command / option that does what I want: only delete the non-conflicting records without the need of listing all constraints manually that the SQL engine is already aware of anyway.

Comment: **"`{EXISTS Query}` is not really good..."* What's wrong with it. Why isn't it "good"? That's exactly what you want.

Comment: You could generate _dynamic SQL_ by using [`sys.foreign_keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to traipse through the relations between tables. Of course that won't catch _check constraints_ or _triggers_ that implement any other business rules that might be important. Or relations that have no implementation in the DB, but everyone _knows_ what they are.

Comment: @HABO yeah building a dynamic SQL is an option indeed, but again, the SQL engine must be doing something similar in run-time, so I'm hoping for a simple static SQL command / option that tells the engine to simply keep the violating records - instead of me listing them manually or dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use an `EXISTS`:

```sql
DELETE P
FROM Persons P
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM dbo.Orders O
                 WHERE O.PersonID = P.PersonID);
```

Another would be to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
DELETE P
FROM Persons P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders O ON P.PersonID = O.PersonID
WHERE O.OrderID IS NULL;
```